# How to make font sizes responsive in Materialize

Tags: css, fonts, media-queries, materialize, responsive

I have problem with font size in materialize. if my client device become smaller text sizes is not responsive and they are so small. one solution is to use @media query for every client devies. this is not my solution because materialize itself has media queries and I don't want rewrite them again.  is there any way to make texts responsive in materialize?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps `font-size:5vw`  where 5 would be 5% of the viewport.  Or each unit of vw is 1% of the viewport width

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <body>
        <div style="font-size:5vw;text-align:center;">This is Some Responsive Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You gives us a key to solve this problem. it works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

*Thanks John!*

I created this add-on for facilitating font-size using materialize:

```
/*  fontSize: */
.xs   {font-size: 0.75rem}
.sm   {font-size: 0.875rem}
.base {font-size: 1rem}
.lg   {font-size: 1.125rem}
.xl   {font-size: 1.25rem}
.2xl  {font-size: 1.5rem}
.3xl  {font-size: 1.875rem}
.4xl  {font-size: 2.25rem}
.5xl  {font-size: 3rem}
.6xl  {font-size: 4rem}
.fs1  {font-size: 1vw}
.fs2  {font-size: 1.4vw}
.fs3  {font-size: 1.6vw}
.fs4  {font-size: 1.8vw}
.fs5  {font-size: 2vw}
.fs6  {font-size: 2.2vw}
.fs7  {font-size: 2.4vw}
.fs8  {font-size: 2.6vw}
```

The unique problem of % font-size is that is too variable text size from mobile (too small) to large-screens (too big)

Comment: This works perfect, voted it.  This build on John's idea, make it handy for me.